# How to make links follow the cursor for a defined distance on hover state?

Tags: javascript, css, gsap

I want to reproduce the link "attraction" effect as shown in the following theme : http://preview.themeforest.net/item/grenada-creative-ajax-portfolio-showcase-slider-theme/full_screen_preview/22712618?_ga=2.243139466.922598619.1568038769-663244003.1563974355

Hover "follow us" on the bottom right of the page to see it in action.

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: I don't even see a "follow us" thing

Comment: I do see it and you can compare that to adding a trail effect to the cursor mouse. If I find an interesting link I will send it, searching "trail effect" should help

Comment: I found that pretty quickly, sorry for horrible music video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jUn8kLFtEjI

Comment: See [this post](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/21161-animated-mouse-cursor/?tab=comments#comment-99361) for how to implement an effect like this with GSAP.

Comment: Thanks for your replies but I think I expressed myself poorly. I'm looking for the hover and magnet effect on links such as the "selected works" in this website : https://igma.im

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i write this example, try this:

```
TweenMax with tilt libraries
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/becher_henchiri/ndj9moxc/1/)

this is my second example:

[Example 2](https://jsfiddle.net/becher_henchiri/c2ef9qry/)

```js
var viewportOffset = {
    x: 0,
    y: $(window).scrollTop()
};

var Magnet = function(elements) {
    elements.each(function() {
        var element = $(this);
        var isMagnetic = false;
        var isTransformed;
        var max = element.attr("offset-hover-max") || .7;
        var min = element.attr("offset-hover-min") || .5;

        function grap(dx, dy) {
            TweenMax.to(element, 0.3, { x: 0.6 * dx, y: 0.6 * dy, rotation: 0.07 * dx, ease: Power2.easeOut })
        };

        function reset() {
            TweenMax.to(element, .7, { x: 0, y: 0, scale: 1, rotation: 0, ease: Elastic.easeOut })
        };

        $(window).on("mousemove", function(e) {
            var mouse = {
                x: e.clientX,
                y: e.clientY - viewportOffset.y
            };
            
            var maxDistance = isMagnetic ? max : min;

            var width = element.outerWidth();
            var height = element.outerHeight();
            var offset = element.offset();
            var center = {
                x: offset.left + width / 2,
                y: offset.top + height / 2
            };
            var dx = mouse.x - center.x;
            var dy = mouse.y - center.y;
            
            isTransformed = false;

            if(Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) < width * maxDistance) {
                isTransformed = true;
                if(!isMagnetic) isMagnetic = true;
                grap(dx, dy);

            }

            if(!isTransformed && isMagnetic) {
                reset();
                isMagnetic = false;
            }
        });
    });
};

$('.magnet-btn').on("mouseenter mouseleave", function(e) {
    var $element = $(this);
    var width = $element.outerWidth();
    var height = $element.outerHeight();
    var x = (e.pageX - $element.offset().left - width / 2) * (width > height ? height / width : 1);
    var y = (e.pageY - $element.offset().top - height / 2) * (height > width ? width / height: 1);
    var $background = $element.find(".magnet-btn__bg");    
    var direction = Math.round((Math.atan2(y, x) * (180 / Math.PI) + 180) / 90 + 3) % 4;
    if ("mouseenter" === e.type) {
        switch (direction) {
            case 0:
                TweenMax.fromTo($background, 0.3, { left: "0%", top: "-100%" }, { top: "0%", left: "0%", ease: Power3.easeOut });
                break;
            case 1:
                TweenMax.fromTo($background, 0.3, { left: "100%", top: "0%" }, { top: "0%", left: "0%", ease: Power3.easeOut });
                break;
            case 2:
                TweenMax.fromTo($background, 0.3, { left: "0%", top: "100%" }, { top: "0%", left: "0%", ease: Power3.easeOut });
                break;
            case 3:
                TweenMax.fromTo($background, 0.3, { left: "-100%", top: "0%" }, { top: "0%", left: "0%", ease: Power3.easeOut });
        }
    } else {
        switch (direction) {
            case 0:
                TweenMax.to($background, 0.3, { left: "0%", top: "-100%", ease: Power3.easeOut });
                break;
            case 1:
                TweenMax.to($background, 0.3, { left: "100%", top: "0%", ease: Power3.easeOut });
                break;
            case 2:
                TweenMax.to($background, 0.3, { left: "0%", top: "100%", ease: Power3.easeOut });
                break;
            case 3:
                TweenMax.to($background, 0.3, { left: "-100%", top: "0%", ease: Power3.easeOut });

        }
    } 
});

var btn = $('.magnet-btn');
Magnet(btn);

$( function() {
        // init plugin
        NodeCursor({
            cursor : true, 
            node : true, 
            cursor_velocity : 1, 
            node_velocity : 0.15, 
            native_cursor : 'none', 
            element_to_hover : '.nodeHover', 
            cursor_class_hover : 'disable', 
            node_class_hover : 'expand', 
            hide_mode : true, 
            hide_timing : 2000, 
        });

    });
```

```css
html, body {
 
  background-color: #111111;
 
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 50px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 14px;
}

ul li a {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.wrapper .magnet-btn {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  transition: color 0.2s ease-in;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

/* ----------------------------

  cursor styles

--------------------------- */
.cursor {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  /*styles applied for showing / hiding cursor - do not touch*/
  transition: opacity 300ms linear;
  opacity: 0;
  /*element width*/
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
}

.cursor.moving {
  opacity: 1;
}

.cursor::before {
  content: ' ';
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  /* transitions animations*/
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 300ms linear;
}

/* expand is the class you assigned with the plugin to cursor when a selected element is hovered*/
.cursor.expand::before {
  opacity: 0;
}

/* ----------------------------

  node styles

--------------------------- */
.node {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  /*styles applied for showing / hiding cursor - do not touch*/
  transition: opacity 300ms linear;
  opacity: 0;
  /*element width*/
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}

.node.moving {
  opacity: 1;
}

.node::before {
  content: ' ';
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  /*states and transitions animations*/
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
          transform: scale(1.5);
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 300ms linear, border 300ms linear, background-color 300ms linear, -webkit-transform 300ms linear;
  transition: opacity 300ms linear, transform 300ms linear, border 300ms linear, background-color 300ms linear;
  transition: opacity 300ms linear, transform 300ms linear, border 300ms linear, background-color 300ms linear, -webkit-transform 300ms linear;
}

/* expand is the class you assigned with the plugin to cursor when a selected element is hovered*/
.node.expand::before {
  -webkit-transform: scale(3);
          transform: scale(3);
  opacity: 0.2;
}

/*.node.reduce {
    transform: scale(1);
    background-color: #ffffff;
}*/
.hover__btn {
  font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 900;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/hmongouachon/NodeCursor/src/nodecursor-jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>


<div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li>
    <a href="#" class="magnet-btn nodeHover" offset-hover-max="0.5" offset-hover-min="0.5">In</a></li>
        
    <li> <a href="#" class="magnet-btn nodeHover" offset-hover-max="0.5" offset-hover-min="0.5">Fb</a></li>
        
        <li> <a href="#" class="magnet-btn nodeHover" offset-hover-max="0.5" offset-hover-min="0.5">Db</a></li>
        
         <li> <a href="#" class="magnet-btn nodeHover" offset-hover-max="0.5" offset-hover-min="0.5">Tw</a></li>
         <li> <a href="#" class="magnet-btn nodeHover" offset-hover-max="0.5" offset-hover-min="0.5">Be</a></li>
       
        
        
    </ul>
</div>

    <!-- create cursor markups  -->
    <div class="node" id="node"></div>
<!--     <div class="cursor" id="cursor"></div> -->
```

Comment: Thanks for your example but I'm looking for an hover "magnet" effect. This site uses that on the "selected works" links : https://igma.im

Comment: try the new example

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for ! Thanks !